# how to resolve host error in tests with php codeception

Tags: database, logging, codeception

I'm new to testing with codeception and after writing my tests concerning the login I ran and got the error below:

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: adminbom.smobilpay.integration.maviance.info (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://adminbom.smobilpay.integration.maviance.info/login

I need help on how to resolve this